# How to Update Mat-Table Data automatically without refresh when Data changes in SQL DB?

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I want to get live data into my Mat-table grid without refreshing the page when i make changes in the SQL Database .

I am trying with Observables and subscribing to it but it doesnt auto refresh and give the live data .

My Component -

```
    getDataForClients(name:string){
    this.dashboardService.getClientsData(name).subscribe(res=>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
  })
```

My Service -

```
 public getClientsData(name:string){
  return this.http.get<any[]>('https://localhost:44395/api/StocksOrders/' + name);
}
```

M HTML -

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="stockName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Stock Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stockName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
     
      <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantity </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.quantityPurchased}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
     
      <ng-container matColumnDef="purchaseDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Purchase Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.quantityPurchased}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
     
      <ng-container matColumnDef="purchasePrice">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Purchase Price </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stockPurchasePrice}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="currentPrice">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Current Price </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stockCurrentPrice}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

What changes will I have to do to achieve that ? Please help.

Comment: What you're looking for is most probably [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) on the front-end. How the back-end handles this is a whole different topic, since it very much depends on your tech stack - so you should probably start with making a separate question about that.